# How to create a UITableView with different UITableViewCell in each row

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create a `UITableView` with different `UITableViewCell` in each row. So in my `UITableViewDataSource`, I did:

```
#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource
// I create a Table with 3 sections, each section with 1 row. 
// In each section I have a different class for my TableCell:
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    NSString *className;
    if (indexPath.row != 0)
        return nil;
    switch (indexPath.section)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            // Header cell
            className = NSStringFromClass([FirstRowCell class]);
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:className
                                                                             forIndexPath:indexPath];
           return cell;
         }
        case 1:
        {
            // Header cell
            className = NSStringFromClass([SecondRowCell class]);
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:className
                                                                             forIndexPath:indexPath];
           return cell;
         }
        case 2:
        {
            // Header cell
            className = NSStringFromClass([ThirdRowCell class]);
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:className
                                                                             forIndexPath:indexPath];
           return cell;
         }
    return nil;
}
```

But I find out that for some reason, my 2nd row cell get create twice. I step thru the code, I don't know why it is being called twice.

Can you please help me figure out what is the cause of my problem?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. Are you sure you gave the cells the correct identifiers in IB?

Comment: Without you doing anything like scrolling? Do you have any other code calling the table view? What are the row heights?

Comment: Did you register all of those cells you want to use?